# I'm struggling with the following pattern in java

Tags: java, algorithm, for-loop

The pattern I want to print is

```
1
1#
1#2
1#2#
1#2#3
1#2#3#
```

I wrote the following code:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        int q = 2;
        for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
                if (j % 2 != 0) {
                    if (j > 2) {
                        System.out.print (q+ "");
                    } else {
                        System.out.print (j + "");
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.print("# ");
                }
            } 
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

and it's output is:

```
1
1# 
1# 2
1# 2# 
1# 2# 2
1# 2# 2#
```

Comment: What is the point of space after `#` in `System.out.print("# ");`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do it like this:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
      for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
          s.append(i);
          System.out.println(s);
          s.append("#");
          System.out.println(s);
      }
    }
}
```

Just keep adding to the string(builder) and print it.

Or, if you don't want to track the state with the StringBuilder, you could do it like this:

```
public class Alternative {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int n = 3;
        for (int i = 0; i < n * 2; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
                if (j % 2 == 0) {
                    System.out.print(j / 2 + 1);
                } else {
                    System.out.print("#");  
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use a `StringBuilder` instead?

Comment: @JohannesKuhn, you are right, that's better. I updated my answer.

Comment: @MarioVarchmin Thanks for the answer, but I was looking for way to solve the question without using StringBuilder/String(buffer) method. Can you help me with that?

Comment: @OnkarBhise, you should then update your question and mention which data types, which methods, which constructs, ...etc you are allowed to use. It is better to provide a white-list, than a black list, as it is quite likely the black list is much longer. On Stack Overflow the aim is to provide efficient solutions, and that explains why StringBuilder is suggested here.

Comment: @OnkarBhise Understood. I hope you like the 2nd solution better :-)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting wrong output because of logic you have written. You can try below code snippet for the same pattern :

```
public class Main {
        public static void main(String args[]) {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
                int q = 1;
                for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
                    if (j % 2 == 0) {
                        System.out.print("#");
                    } else {
                        System.out.print(q);
                        q++;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
```